# Why do I need to publish my project.json when setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I start a new website, with to  default  VS2015 template for ASP.NET Core.  Just for testing purpose I published It 'as is' on Azure.

I set my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development on my Azure Website (Paas).

I set the environment variable directly in the Azure Management Portal for my Website as:
[image]

But when I do that I get :
[image]

So  By default ASPNET Core on Azure is set to  "Production" Environment.  When I leave it that way I don't need my  "project.json".  But When i Add the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  I need to publish the project.json file witch is not publish automatically using VS2015 Built-In tools and/or using a linked git repository.

Is there a way to simplify this behavior or do I missed something?

Comment: How are you publishing your project? are you uploading it through FTP? Publishing it through Visual Studio? Continuous integration from your repository?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Oh Good Remark.  I Publish It with Built-In tools of VisualStudio.  But,  still, it's worked if Environment Setting is untouched

Comment: I try to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`  Development, it works correctly. From my experience, there is no need to publish the project.json file to azure. So it is very odd that get this error. Please have a try to create another WebApp and try again.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT  We did a couple of try and every time we encountered the same result on Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clue is in your stack trace.  It's trying to look into project.json to figure out where your user secrets file is, which is only supposed to be used for local development and is enabled in the "Development" environment if using the default template.  For my development/testing environments in Azure App Services, I set the Environment to "Staging", which I typically have configured the same as "Development" except for pulling user secrets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets